# Save NSManaged object with UITextField Changes

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Is it good to save to core data whenever a edit is made to UITextField.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [nameField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    [yearField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}


-(void) textFieldValueChanged:(UITextField*) field{
    NSIndexPath *path=[self getEditingIndexPath];
    Car *carObject=[fetchController objectAtIndexPath:path];
    switch (field.tag) {
        case 1:
            carObject.name=field.text;
            break;
        case 2:
            carObject.year=[field.text intValue];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
   NSError *e;
   [managedContext save:&e];
}
```

The idea behind this approach to eliminate "**Save**" button.

So, any better approach with just a flow will be helpful.

Comment: save only when navigating away form the current view controller, and only if the context `hasChanges` (only update the edited object don't save right away)?

Comment: So, If I insert, add , remove, edit all the changes should be committed (save) in viewWillDisappear, by checking haschanges and then call save.

Comment: depending on the importance of the information (you might want a timed save) and user experience you would like to establish. also, on app termination.